# android while loop wait for server response using parse server

Tags: android, parsing, while-loop, response, server

I developed an android turn based game and so far I can make the first move but when I want the user would wait for the second player to play the app crashes.
What I tried to do is when the player finishes his move I call a function like this:

```
public void TheThread()
    {
        boolean fy=false;


                while(!fy)
                {
                    if(CheckMove2())
                        fy=true;
                }
    }
```

The checkmove2 function connects the parse table and check if is there a turn and return boolean.
I beleive this is not the right way to do it,thanks for your help.

Edit:

```
ChecKmove2() function:
private boolean CheckMove2() {

         fx=false;

        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("serverturn");
        query.whereEqualTo("Receiver", Sender);
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {
            public void done(ParseObject updatePO, ParseException ParseError) {

                if(ParseError == null){
         fx=true;
         String objID;
                   x=updatePO.getInt("x");
                   y=updatePO.getInt("y");
                   try {
                    updatePO.delete();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
///here comes the game algorithm.
if(fx)
           return true;
       return false;
}
```

Edit: the app not crashes its just stop and alert: "The app is not responding" and then asks if I want to wait or close the app.The checkmove function works perfectly I checked it with other devices,the problem is to use this checkmove function in a while loop so the user would wait for the opponent turn.

Comment: What does your logcat say when the app crashes? What does your CheckMove2 function look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is crashing because in that scenario you've caused an endless loop (if there are no other moves waiting). So the OS will, most likely force close your application because it thinks its become unresponsive.

What you're better off doing is this:

1. Create a background service with an AyncTask to check for other players moves at specific intervals (10 - 15 mins maybe?)
2. Once a move is found. Alert the player to it by using a Notification which would link to your app via an `Intent`

As a side note, you should always use background threads/async tasks etc to talk to networks.

Answer (score 0):

On your place i would do next:

In parse cloudCode afterSave or beforeSave of the object you are waiting for, send a socket message to your app when the needed object is updated. For example using pubnub.com

I think this is a decent solution, but running some loopy checking logic seemes so unprofessional.

In general it works like this:

1. two players subscribe to a channel
2. when one finishes move, from cloud code send a message to this
   channel
3. catch it in your app.

The message can trigger update from parse or can contain the needed data itself.